# Parallel Programming in Python with Pool.Map() comparing MAC OSX & Windows 10

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

Very simple program after searching various possibilities to do multiprocessing in Python 3.X.

Running the program on MAC and Windows provides different results. MAC has parallel processing taking less time compared to Serial. I read various notes on IPC overhead etc. as this is a trivial function to process but than why on MAC OSX the results are way better.

Basically someone who know the MAC OSX architecture to deal with Pool.MAP() can provide input. Thanks in advance.

```
**On MAC OSX**
cpu_count() = 4
Creating pool with 4 processes
pool = <multiprocessing.pool.Pool object at 0x1019d96a0>
Time for y_parallel =  2.866562843322754
Time for y_serial =  10.207499027252197


**On Windows**
cpu_count() = 4
Creating pool with 4 processes
pool = <multiprocessing.pool.Pool object at 0x031A1CD0>
Time for y_parallel =  13.155309915542603
Time for y_serial =  10.025831460952759

    import multiprocessing
    import time

    def f(x):
         time.sleep(0.1)
         return x+1

    # Serially adding 100 numbers (X+1) to y_serial
    y_serial = []
    x = range(100)
    startTime_serial = time.time()
    #for i in x:
    #    y_serial = y_serial + [f(i)]
    y_serial += map(f,x)
    endTime_serial = time.time()


    #Letting Pool allocate processes through map.Pool
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        print('cpu_count() = %d' % multiprocessing.cpu_count())
        PROCESSES = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
        print('Creating pool with %d processes' % PROCESSES)
        pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
        print('pool = %s' % pool)
        startTime_parallel = time.time()
        y_parallel = pool.map(f,x)
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
        endTime_parallel = time.time()
        print("Time for y_parallel = ", endTime_parallel - startTime_parallel)
        print ("Time for y_serial = ", endTime_serial - startTime_serial)
        print ("y_parallel", y_parallel)
        print ("y_serial=", y_serial)
```